# Slow data transfer from Azure Blob Storage to compute target

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

It's taking 1 hour to download a 48gb dataset with 90000 files.
I am training an image segmentation model on Azure ML pipeline using compute target p100-nc6s-v2.
In my script I'm accessing Azure Blob Storage using DataReference's as_download() functionality. The blob storage is in the same location as workspace (using get_default_datastore).

**Note:** I'm able to download complete dataset to local workstation within a few minutes using `az copy`.

When I tried to use as_mount() the first epoch was extremely slow (4700 seconds vs 772 seconds for subsequent epochs).

Is this expected behavior? If not, what can be done to improve dataset loading speed?

Comment: What is your question please?

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 2):

Working folder of the run is mounted cloud storage, which could be defaulting to file storage in your workspace.
Can you try setting blob datastore instead, and see if perf improves?

```
run_config.source_directory_data_store = 'workspaceblobstore'
```

Answer (score 2):

`as_download()` downloads the data to the current working directory, which is a mouted file-share (or blob if you do what @reznikov suggested).
Unfortunately, for small files, neither blob nor file-share are very performant (although blob is much better) -- see this reply for some measurements: [Disk I/O extremely slow on P100-NC6s-V2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57971689/disk-i-o-extremely-slow-on-p100-nc6s-v2/57977973#57977973)

When you are mounting, the reason that the first epoch is so slow, lies in the fact that blob fuse (which is used for mounting blobs) caches to the local SSD, so for after the first epoch, everything is on your SSD and you get the full performance.

As for why the first epoch takes much longer than the `az copy`, I would suspect that the data reader of the framework you are using does not pipeline the reads. What are you using?

You could try one of 2 things:

1. Mount, but at the beginning of the job, copy the data from the mount path to /tmp and consume it from there.
2. If #1 is significantly slower than `az copy`, then, don't mount. Instead, at the beginning of the job, copy the data to /tmp using `az copy`.